# Tag excerpts on search pages are missing tags

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

The excerpt from a tag wiki as shown when a question's tag is hovered over is shown as typed. However, on the search page, tags are stripped. For example, [doctype](/questions/tagged/doctype)'s excerpt reads:

```
A doctype declaration defines a document's type definition. It should be the very
first thing in an HTML document, before the <html> tag.
```

However, when shown on [the search page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctype), it's missing the tag:

> A doctype declaration defines a document's type definition. It should be the very
>       first thing in an HTML document, before the tag.

Not an XSS vulnerability, at least...

Comment: Yeah, that's weird.  It eats the angle brackets, but doesn't respond to the backtick escape character, and the tag dropdown doesn't recognize backtick anyway.

Comment: Came across the issue yesterday with [tag:select].

Comment: Still an issue, and it appears to come dangerously close to being a security flaw.